# Wifi adapter only works if unplug and replug

Tags: drivers, wireless, adapter

Im having a problem here: i need to unplug and replug the adapter every time i started the sistem to work. I dont know what can i do.

Someone can help me?

Thanks!

Comment: This is perhaps not a solution to the real problem, but may be more convenient than to unplug and replug the adapter: you can restart the network-manager servie like this: `sudo service network-manager restart` -- does that help?

Comment: Hello! Thank for the answwer but dont works =\
only works if i replug the adapter